# compare two groups based on categorial variable in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, frequency

I have created `df` which contains more than 8,000 firm years

`gvkey` = company id

`fam` = dummy (equals 1 if firm is family firm)

`industry` = categorial variable

```
   gvkey   fam  industry
1   1004    0     6
2   1004    0     6
3   1004    0     6
4   1004    0     6
5   1004    0     6
6   1013    0     4
7   1013    0     4
8   1013    0     4
9   1013    0     4
10  1013    0     4
11  1013    0     4
12  1045    0     5
13  1045    0     5
14  1045    0     5
15  1045    0     5
16  1045    0     5
17  1045    0     5
18  1072    0     4
19  1072    0     4
20  1072    0     4
21  1072    0     4
22  1072    0     4
23  1076    1     9
24  1076    1     9
25  1076    1     9
26  1076    1     9
27  1076    1     9
28  1076    1     9
29  1078    0     4
30  1078    0     4
31  1078    0     4
32  1078    0     4
33  1078    0     4
34  1078    0     4
35  1121    1     6
36  1121    1     6
37  1121    1     6
38  1121    1     6
39  1121    1     6
40  1121    1     6
41  1161    0     4
42  1161    0     4
43  1161    0     4
44  1161    0     4
45  1161    0     4
46  1161    0     4
47  1209    0     4
48  1209    0     4
49  1209    0     4
50  1209    0     4
...
```

This is how the output should kind of look like. Industry description = `industry`

[image: This is the final output that I want to create in my paper. The column industry description equals my column industry]

**verbal logic:**

1) For all unique `gvkey` create a column which counts the number of fam = 0 in each industry.

2) For all unique `gvkey` create a column which counts the number of fam = 1 in each industry.

3) Create an output which shows the frequencies of family firms and non family firms for each idnustry

Maybe it even possible to execute this in one code?!

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` otion could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(industry) %>%
 summarise(n_family = n_distinct(gvkey[fam == 1]),
           n_no_family = n_distinct(gvkey[fam == 0]),
           perc_family = n_family/n_distinct(gvkey)*100) 

  industry n_family n_no_family perc_family
     <int>    <int>       <int>       <dbl>
1        4        0           5           0
2        5        0           1           0
3        6        1           1          50
4        9        1           0         100
```

Answer (score 2):

Your verbal logic is not very clear to me (particularly the statements regarding unique `gvkey` for the final output), but here I provide two results so you can see which one is the thing you want:

- **result 1**: using `unique(df)` for count

```
dfout <- `colnames<-`(data.frame(as.matrix(aggregate(fam ~industry,
                                                     unique(df),
                                                     FUN = function(x) c(sum(x==0),sum(x==1),sum(x==1)/length(x)*100)))), 
                      c("Industry", "FamCnt", "NoFamCnt", "FamPerc"))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Industry FamCnt NoFamCnt FamPerc
1        4      5        0       0
2        5      1        0       0
3        6      1        1      50
4        9      0        1     100
```

- **result 2**: using `df` for count

```
dfout <- `colnames<-`(data.frame(as.matrix(aggregate(fam ~industry,
                                                     df,
                                                     FUN = function(x) c(sum(x==0),sum(x==1),sum(x==1)/length(x)*100)))), 
                      c("Industry", "FamCnt", "NoFamCnt", "FamPerc"))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Industry FamCnt NoFamCnt   FamPerc
1        4     27        0   0.00000
2        5      6        0   0.00000
3        6      5        6  54.54545
4        9      0        6 100.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution (note: it isn't typically good practice to keep spaces in vector names)

```
# Reshape / Rename the input data: 

ir_df <- setNames(reshape(setNames(aggregate(.~fam+industry, df, length),

                                           c("fam", "industry", "count")),
               direction = "wide",

               idvar = "industry", 

               timevar = "fam"), c("Industry", "Nonfamily Firms", "Family Firms"))

# Transform the data frame to contain the final equation: 

final_df <- transform(replace(ir_df, is.na(ir_df), 0), 

                      `Percent Family Firms In Industry` = 

                        round(`Family Firms` /

                        rowSums(ir_df[,grepl("family", tolower(names(ir_df)))], na.rm = TRUE)

                      * 100, 2))
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(gvkey = c(1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1013L, 
1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1045L, 1045L, 1045L, 1045L, 
1045L, 1045L, 1072L, 1072L, 1072L, 1072L, 1072L, 1076L, 1076L, 
1076L, 1076L, 1076L, 1076L, 1078L, 1078L, 1078L, 1078L, 1078L, 
1078L, 1121L, 1121L, 1121L, 1121L, 1121L, 1121L, 1161L, 1161L, 
1161L, 1161L, 1161L, 1161L, 1209L, 1209L, 1209L, 1209L), fam = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), industry = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```